# Modal close and form value reset not working in Angular

Tags: angular, mdbootstrap

Crossing with many existing questions related to my question, I post this. So don't comment this as duplicate and send duplicate answers my scenario is a little bit different. All solutions are related to javascript or jquery. But I want in Angular.

I am using **mdBootstrap**, providing only the CDN link in index.html not installing it. I have a popup with tabs for login & Register. The problem is after entering credentials and click login modal is not closing(I don't want to put data-dismiss="modal") as it closes the modal without doing login functionality. I want both functions to be done, validating the credentials if it is invalid, I want the modal is in open saying error message. If it is valid then only modal to be closed.

The second thing I want to reset the modal form values even when I click anywhere outside the modal and reopen the modal. For example, if I have two input fields like username and password, I entered only the username leaving the password blank and click outside and reopen the modal, my modal opened with the entered username value. I want to get rid of these problems.

Anyone help me to fix these issues. Thanks in Advance.

Log-Reg.component.html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalLoginRegisterForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        //tabs for login & Register
        <div class="tab-content py-0">
          <div class="tab-pane fade in show active" id="modalLoginTab" role="tabpanel">
            <form #loginForm="ngForm">
              <div class="md-form">
                <input required [(ngModel)]="username" type="email" id="loginEmail" name="Username" class="form-control validate">
                <label for="loginEmail">Enter your email address</label>
              </div>
              <div class="md-form">
                <input required [(ngModel)]="password" type="password" id="loginPassword" name="Password" class="form-control validate">
                <label for="loginPassword">Enter your password</label>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="isLoginError" class="alert alert-danger">Incorrect Credentials</div>
              <button type="button" [disabled]=!loginForm.valid class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onLogin()">Login</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          //Form for Register
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Log-Reg.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('loginForm') public userLoginForm : NgForm;

onLogin(){
//some function for login validation\
this.userLoginForm.reset();
}
```

Comment: add your code in stackblitz

Comment: actually modal is not closing or validation is not being done ? I couldn't able to get you whats the actual problem

Comment: validation is done but modal is not closing.only if i click the close button on top the modal gets closed

Comment: @Chellappan https://angular-zsdwz4.stackblitz.io/#modalRegisterTab

Comment: @Arthi not able to acces code editor

Comment: @Chellappan https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsdwz4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Chellappan try to solve without  installing mdBootstrap(just use CDN Links)

Comment: okay i will try

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
this.userLoginForm.form.reset()
```

or

```
this.userLoginForm.resetForm()
```

Comment: `this.userLoginForm` should be a `FormGroup`. And if it is, there will be an error *`form` does not exist on `FormGroup`*

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/modal-close-and-form-value-reset-not-working-in-angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @KrishnaRathore how to do the validation here. Form values reset without validating

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: I don't know how to hard code the login values. am using web api service for that so not able to post it

Comment: could you provide developer code link of stackblitz ?

Comment: @KrishnaRathore Actually at the beginning of my question i mentioned i didn't install mdBootstrap just use CDN links in index.html

Comment: @KrishnaRathore Am getting error near chart.js while installing that's y am using CDN Links

Comment: npm i angular-bootstrap-md --save ,  npm install chart.js --save , npm install bootstrap , npm install jquery

Answer (score 0):

From your Comment I assume that you could not able to close the modal after Login,

you are not importing the Modal Directive in your Component

**Modal Template .html file**

```
 <div mdbModal #loginModal="mdbModal" class="modal fade" id="modalLoginRegisterForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        //tabs for login & Register
        <div class="tab-content py-0">
          <div class="tab-pane fade in show active" id="modalLoginTab" role="tabpanel">
            <form #loginForm="ngForm">
              <div class="md-form">
                <input required [(ngModel)]="username" type="email" id="loginEmail" name="Username" class="form-control validate">
                <label for="loginEmail">Enter your email address</label>
              </div>
              <div class="md-form">
                <input required [(ngModel)]="password" type="password" id="loginPassword" name="Password" class="form-control validate">
                <label for="loginPassword">Enter your password</label>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="isLoginError" class="alert alert-danger">Incorrect Credentials</div>
              <button type="button" [disabled]=!loginForm.valid class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onLogin()">Login</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          //Form for Register
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your Component file (**appcomponent.ts**) try this

```
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng-mdb-pro/free/modals/modal.directive';

    @ViewChild('loginModal') _loginModal: ModalDirective;

    onLogin(){
    *add your login logic in your success add the below code*
    this._loginModal.hide()
    }
```

hope this solve your problem

Comment: I mentioned in the question as am not installing mdBootstrap just use the CDN links.

Comment: Is there any other way to resolve this issue without installing mdBootstrap?

Comment: I don't think so with in the CDN you cant able to access their ModalDirective, if you still need it create your own directive which can access the element from their you can control it

Comment: Hi @Arthi plz check https://angular-qxc8rh.stackblitz.io

and let me know this url is working fine?

Comment: Hi @KrishnaRathore could you provide developer code link of stackblitz?

Comment: Let me check in my code and let you know. Do you install mdBootstrap in it?